# Casting between sequential unsafe structs

Tags: c#, linux, sockets, netlink

I'm trying to port some [netlink socket](http://qos.ittc.ku.edu/netlink/html/node6.html) code from C to C#. The code is the same as in the link:

First, we port `sockaddr_nl` structure ([c source](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/netlink.h#L36)):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct sockaddr_nl
{
    public ushort nl_family;
    public ushort nl_pad;
    public uint nl_pid;
    public uint nl_groups;
}
```

Then, get a socket fd using

```
var fd = -1;
fd = UnixFiller.socket(
    (int) UnixAddressFamily.AF_NETLINK,
    (int) UnixSocketType.SOCK_RAW | 0x80000,
    0 /* NETLINK_ROUTE */
);
if(fd < 0)
    FatalError("Failed to create routing socket.");
```

`UnixFiller.socket` is just a DLLImport from libc. This call succeeds as expected.

However, the next step would be to cast the expressive `sockaddr_nl` structure to the family + byte array structure `sockaddr` consumed by bind:

```
bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address));
```

Where [`sockaddr` is](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/socket.h#L29)

```
struct sockaddr {
    sa_family_t sa_family;  /* address family, AF_xxx   */
    char        sa_data[14];    /* 14 bytes of protocol address */
};
```

Which, as far as I know, would be this in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct sockaddr
{
    public ushort sa_familiy;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 14)] byte[] sa_data;
}
```

**Question**

First, how should the `bind` import look like?

```
[DllImport("libc", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "bind")]
public static extern int bind(int sockfd, ??? addr, int addrlen);
```

??? = unknown.

Next, how can I port the cast from `sockaddr_nl` to `sockaddr` in order to pass the right format to `bind`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't *cast* between `sockaddr_nl` and `sockaddr` because you have a reference (`sa_data`) that is going to get in the way. If it was a `fixed` buffer instead (i.e. raw data directly in the struct), then it would probably be fine, but *then* you need to use `unsafe` throughout. However, I'm unclear what that would look like; It looks like you mean that the 14 bytes of `sa_data` shuld be the contents of `sockaddr_nl` ? (I only count 12 bytes, note)

To write a struct over a `byte[]`, you can use `unsafe` code:

```
static unsafe void Main()
{
    var val = new sockaddr_nl
    {
        nl_family = 1, nl_pad = 2, nl_pid = 3, nl_groups = 4
    };
    byte[] data = new byte[14];
    Console.WriteLine("size of struct: " + sizeof(sockaddr_nl));
    // show value before
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(data));
    // thunk over the data
    fixed (byte* p = data)
    {
        *((sockaddr_nl*)p) = val;
    }
    // show value after
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(data));
}
```

This has the output:

```
size of struct: 12
00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
01-00-02-00-03-00-00-00-04-00-00-00-00-00
```

Comment: Correct, `sockaddr_nl` is 12 bytes, while `sockaddr` is 16. Both have the initial family value (`sa_family`), which as far as I understand, stays the same when casted. Then the data field array will contain the pid and group field of `sockaddr_nl`. `nl_pad` is just there to pad the struct size. I'm basically just trying to implement this construct: `(struct sockaddr*)&address`